# MYSQL LONGTEXT field being truncated on retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I have a LONGTEXT field that's been set to utf8_general_ci, It holds a large JSON value, when I look at the value in phpmyadmin I can see the beginning and the end of the JSON text (its also valid).

But when I print out the JSON column to the screen I only get half of the text and that is before calling json_decode which returns NULL.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
$stmtproducts = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?');  
$stmtproducts->execute([$id]); 

$product = $stmtproducts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($product['json_txt']);
```

I have already changed the

> max_allowed_packet

to 512M but the text is still being truncated.

Comment: If `json_decode()` returns `NULL` it means it got an error, and `json_last_error()` will tell you what it is.

Comment: There's probably an encoding problem.

Comment: @Barmar it returns null because the json is incomplete, and the json_last_error() confirmed this by returning error code 4 which corresponds to JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX.